# Do IntentServices eat up an applications memory?

Tags: java, android

I have 5 IntentServices that run at different times and in a separate process than the main UI. When the services complete they send the data via an intent to the main process. I am wondering if having 5 services is using too much memory for my application. Are services completely cleaned from memory when they shutdown or are they still allocating memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `IntentService` automatically shuts down when there is no more work to do. After that, it should be eligible for garbage collection, assuming you have not done something to introduce a memory leak.

That being said, I would think it makes more sense to have one `IntentService` that performs all five functions, examining the incoming `Intent` to determine which thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems each service consumes some memory. Here is good discussion on this topic. [Android service components facts](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/)

Answer (score 0):

You got nothing to be worry about, Android OS running dozens of services at the same time, it is completely safety.